# Group Standard Deviations by Factors

Tags: lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I have a model of the form:

```
library(nlme)
lme1 <- lme(
  y ~ 1,
  random  = ~ Var1 + Var2 | J,
  weights = varIdent(form= ~ 1|Var1*Var2),
  data = df
)
```

I want to estimate the **standard deviations of the groups** `J` based on factors `Var1` and `Var2` (the `random` argument in the model), and the **standard deviations of the observations within groups** based on factors `Var1` and `Var2` (the `weights` argument in the model).

In this example `Var1` and `Var2` both have two levels `a` and `b`.

I can get the standard deviations of the observations within groups using:

```
sigma(lme1)*coef(lme1$modelStruct$varStruct, unconstrained=FALSE, allCoef=TRUE)

# Which gives:
#      a*a       a*b       b*a       b*b 
# 9.205590  8.052488 12.427807 11.533546
```

How would I find the standard deviations of the groups?

```
VarCorr(lme1)

#J = pdLogChol(Var1 + Var2) 
#            Variance  StdDev   Corr         
#(Intercept) 548.99374 23.43062 (Intr) Var1b 
#Var1b       412.81370 20.31782  0.612       
#Var2b       272.71690 16.51414 -0.810 -0.764
#Residual     84.74288  9.20559
```

This is a simulated example, so I know about what the values should be, but don't know how to calculate them from the model.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just figured it out. The results seem to make sense.

````
#The matrix for the portion of the model would be of the form:
#   (Intercept) Var1b Var2b
#           1     0     0
#           1     0     1
#           1     1     0
#           1     1     1

# So for the first row I simply need var(Intercept)
# Second row is var(Intercept + Var2b)
# Third row is var(Intercept + Var1b)
# Fourth row is var(Intercept + Var1b + Var2b)

# For this, what I expect is about:
#23.5 13.9 35.0 25.2

# What I get is:
(vc <- getVarCov(lme1))
sqrt(vc[1,1])                                                       #23.43062
sqrt(sum(diag(vc)[c(1,3)]) + 2*vc[1,3])                             #13.97188
sqrt(sum(diag(vc)[c(1,2)]) + 2*vc[1,2])                             #39.29574
sqrt(sum(diag(vc)[c(1,2,3)]) + 2*vc[1,2] + 2*vc[1,3] + 2*vc[2,3])   #26.03314
```
````